# Pivot data based on category and date field

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle11g, sql-server-2012

I have to identify the records with check_in category of S1, T1 and P1 in the check-in-order and pivot the rest of the data until we hit the next category. I was able to mark the category but was unsuccessful to pickup the min and max dates of each category as the check_in values are different for every row.

Here is the sample data and the expected results. Appreciate your help.

Source:

```
GRPNBR      CHECK_IN    Date_of_check_in    CHECK_IN_ORDER  
200-001     S1          1/15/2020           3   
200-001     Y23         3/4/2020            15  
200-001     M56         5/6/2020            17  
200-001     UN          8/31/2020           38  
200-001     T1          10/12/2020          78  
200-001     C T28       11/23/2020          91  
200-001     C M3        1/29/2021           93  
200-001     P1          4/22/2021           94  
200-001     CM9         8/4/2021            95  
200-001     CM10        9/4/2021            97
```

Expected Result:

```
GRPNBR  CHECK_IN    POST_CHECK_IN   Date_of_check_in    CHECK_IN_ORDER
200-001 S1          Y23             3/4/2020            15
200-001 S1          M56             5/6/2020            17
200-001 S1          UN              8/31/2020           38
200-001 T1          C T28           11/23/2020          91
200-001 T1          C M3            1/29/2021           93
200-001 P1          CM9             8/4/2021            95
200-001 P1          CM10            9/4/2021            97
```

Comment: Always best to provide sample data as formatted text and not images

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach that utilizes the window functions to flag and sequence data and then a simple aggregation for the final results

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=cd0ccda31a409b521512107f2dfc2553)**

```
with cte1 as ( 
Select *
      ,Grp = sum( case when CHECK_IN like '_1' then 1 else 0 end ) over ( partition by [GRPNBR] order by date_of_check_in)
From YourTable
)
, cte2 as (
Select * 
      ,RN  = row_number() over ( partition by Grp order by date_of_check_in)
     ,_Check_In = max( case when CHECK_IN like '_1' then CHECK_IN end ) over ( partition by Grp )
 From  cte1 
)
Select GRPNBR
      ,Check_In  = _Check_In
      ,Post_Check_In = max( Check_In )
      ,Date_of_check_in = max(Date_of_check_in)
      ,Check_In_Order   = max(Check_In_Order)
 From  cte2
 Where RN>1
 Group By GRPNBR,_Check_In,Grp,RN
 Order By Grp,RN
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Your data

| GRPNBR | CHECK_IN | Date_of_check_in | CHECK_IN_ORDER | FIELD5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 200-001 | S1 | 1/15/2020 | 3 |  |
| 200-001 | Y23 | 3/4/2020 | 15 |  |
| 200-001 | M56 | 5/6/2020 | 17 |  |
| 200-001 | UN | 8/31/2020 | 38 |  |
| 200-001 | T1 | 10/12/2020 | 78 |  |
| 200-001 | C | T28 | 11/23/2020 | 91 |
| 200-001 | C | M3 | 1/29/2021 | 93 |
| 200-001 | P1 | 4/22/2021 | 94 |  |
| 200-001 | CM9 | 8/4/2021 | 95 |  |
| 200-001 | CM10 | 9/4/2021 | 97 |  |

to get value like  S1, T1 and P1 ,use following query

```
select GRPNBR,CHECK_IN,Date_of_check_in
from YourTable
where CHECK_IN like   '_1'
```

| GRPNBR | CHECK_IN | Date_of_check_in |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 200-001 | S1 | 2020-01-15 |
| 200-001 | T1 | 2020-10-12 |
| 200-001 | P1 | 2021-04-22 |

then you want to join with following query

```
select GRPNBR,CHECK_IN as POST_CHECK_IN   ,Date_of_check_in,CHECK_IN_ORDER
from YourTable
where CHECK_IN not like   '_1'
```

with following result to get your desired result

| GRPNBR | POST_CHECK_IN | Date_of_check_in | CHECK_IN_ORDER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 200-001 | Y23 | 2020-03-04 | 15 |
| 200-001 | M56 | 2020-05-06 | 17 |
| 200-001 | UN | 2020-08-31 | 38 |
| 200-001 | C T28 | 2020-11-23 | 91 |
| 200-001 | C M3 | 2021-01-29 | 93 |
| 200-001 | CM9 | 2021-08-04 | 95 |
| 200-001 | CM10 | 2021-09-04 | 97 |

I used `Pivot`, `Subquery` and `Case` to get your desired result

```
SELECT A.grpnbr,
       CASE
         WHEN date_of_check_in > s1
              AND date_of_check_in < t1 THEN 'S1'
         WHEN date_of_check_in > t1
              AND date_of_check_in < p1 THEN 'T1'
         WHEN date_of_check_in > p1 THEN 'P1'
       END AS CHECK_IN,
       post_check_in,
       date_of_check_in,
       check_in_order
FROM   (SELECT grpnbr,
               check_in AS POST_CHECK_IN,
               date_of_check_in,
               check_in_order
        FROM   yourtable
        WHERE  check_in NOT LIKE '_1') A
       JOIN (SELECT *
             FROM   (SELECT grpnbr,
                            check_in,
                            date_of_check_in
                     FROM   yourtable
                     WHERE  check_in LIKE '_1') src
                    PIVOT ( Max(date_of_check_in)
                          FOR check_in IN ([S1],
                                           [T1],
                                           [P1]) ) piv) B
         ON A.grpnbr = B.grpnbr
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=c2ddf1f0b0c2cdb21c7e91428318b57d)

Comment: Thank you. I am testing both the solutions and I will get back or close the question if I get the desired output. Appreciate you both.